# Random displacement of the vertices of the sphere from the center outwards

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have a flattened low-poly sphere.
[image]

I need the vertices to be offset by a random amount along the Z-axis using the geometry nodes, but relative to their normal, ie not the global Z-axis, so that the shape looks like an asymmetric star. In other words, the displacement should go from the center in all directions to the outside, so that something like this comes out:
[image]

Unfortunately, I can only move it along the global Z axis..
[image]

[image] (Blender version: 3.6.0)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Offset Vertices from normal:
[image]

Result:
[image]

Comment: Great. But what exactly does "Power" node do?

Comment: Values closer to 1.0 become much rarer. Change the exponent to control the density of the needles.

Answer (score 4):

The only adjustment you need is to use some scale of the *Normal* to offset vertices, instead of Object-Z:

[image]

This version selects points around an icosphere to offset outwards:

[image]